# List comprehension not working as expected

Tags: python, list-comprehension

The following list comprehension `users = [item for item in out.split() if domain in item and userl in item]` as it suggests it should only add users to the `users()` if they meet the `domain` and `userl` criteria. However I'm getting empty results in the `sorted_list`. Can anyone suggest why?

```
domain = 'domainanme'
user_list = [test1, test2, test3]
new_list = []

for userl in user_list:
    try:
        out = subprocess.check_output(["tasklist", "/V", "/FO", "List", "/FI", "USERNAME eq {0}\{1}" .format(domain, userl)], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        users = [item for item in out.split() if domain in item and userl in item]
        sorted_list = set(users)
        print sorted_list
        if sorted_list != None:   # this was an attempted to remove the EMPTY items
            for name in sorted_list:
                print name
                new_list.append(name)
            else:
                pass
```

print name output

```
set([])
set([])
set([])
```

This is what the output looks like:

[image: tasklist output]

Comment: Is `item` a list or a string?

Comment: @Yaw im not entirely sure im assuming a string as its output from tasklist cmd.

Comment: It would help if you could give us a sample `tasklist` output; what does `out` *contain*?

Comment: `out.split()` produces a list of strings, so `item` is single string. It sounds like any single string `item` cannot contain both a domain name and a user name. Showing a sample of what `out` looks like would clear this up.

Comment: out looks like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3ockkyops7udgb2/ScreenHunter_25%20Mar.%2030%2010.19.jpg) (it was far to much output to place in comments)

Comment: Next time, just put the **text** into your post; a screenshot is not nearly as useful; text I could use to create a quick demo.

Comment: Ok will keep that in mind for next time

Answer (score 0):

The domain name in the output is uppercased; make sure you take that into account. Normalize the case for *both* to ensure a case-insensitive match:

```
users = [item for item in out.split() if domain.upper() in item.upper() and userl in item]
```

I'd parse that output a little more intelligently as the above can easily lead to false-positives (a process name that has both the domain and username in it, even as overlapping text, would match too).